# jquery elements selecting from diffrent forms on button click listners

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-selectors

ok so i have three forms on the front page of my site and im not the best with jquery selectors or the .each functions .... so i have the j query ui buttons linked to an event listener thats sends an ajax post but the problem is i cant just specifies the form i want ! heres my code

```
<form>
fields......
fields......
fields......
fields......
<button>register</button>
</form>
<form>
fields......
fields......
fields......
fields......
fields......
<button>login</button>
</form>
<form>
fields......
fields......
fields......
fields......
fields......
<button>book</button>
</form>
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(event) {
        $('form .... i wanna hide all forms once clicked .. working!!!').hide();
        event.preventDefault();
        $('pload').html('<img src="source/image/lbl.gif">');
             // heres where i get the data from all forms i just want one....
        var page = 'form.'+$('form').serialize();
        var huh = $('input:hidden').val();
        var data = 'pop='+huh+'&page='+page;
        $.post('source/php/bots/authorize.php',data,function(data){
                $('#pager_master_div').html(data);
                $('pload').html('');
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the form in which the button that gets clicked lives:

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {

    //stop the form from submitting normally since you are handling the submission with AJAX
    event.preventDefault();

    var $parentForm = $(this).parents('form'),//get this button's form
        page        = 'form.' + $parentForm.serialize(),//serialize the selected form
        huh         = $parentForm.find('input:hidden').val();//get the value of the hidden input in the selected form
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vrjxr/

Comment: i cant get the form to stop refreshing the page ???? should i just attach the return false in the buttons

Comment: @YoungnateDaGreat Yup, if you are handling the submission of the form with AJAX by yourself then you want to use either `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` (note that in a jQuery event handler `return false` is the same as calling `event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

So, replace:

```
var page = 'form.'+$('form').serialize();
```

for:

```
var page = "form."+$(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

So you gonna get the  which is the closest parent of the clicked button (this).

Is there a problem with that `$('input:hidden')` selector? I couldn't be sure by the question, but if so, you can put `$(this).closest('form')` into a variable and then use `variable.find('input:hidden')`.